# latex issue (figure path) + table format

Tags: latex

**Issue 1:** Compiling issue for line 3 below (unsure if file path or something else): Note: file path is correct and was auto-completed by latex (using overleaf)

```
\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{emnlp2023-latex/figures/fig4.png}
     \caption{Pathologization index (3-year rolling mean) of mental health-related terms over the study period (1970-2016).}
     \label{fig:pathol-index}
\end{figure}
```

**Issue 2:** How do I merge the 2 rows in column 1 (position: row2:3) while keeping rows 2 and 3 separated by a horizontal line for col 2:5

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 \textbf{Term} & \textbf{$\beta$(sev)} & \textbf{$\beta$(sev)+} & \textbf{$\beta$(path)} & \textbf{$\beta$(path)+} \\ 
 \hline
\multirow{2}{4em}{addiction} & -0.004* & -0.005* & 0.0007* & 0.0008* \\ 
 \hline
 & -0.008* & -0.008* & 0.00004 & -0.00002 \\
 \hline
\multirow{2}{3em}{anger} & -0.002* & -0.002* & 0.00002 & 6.63^{\text{e-06} \\ 
 & -0.0009 & -0.0009 & 0.00002 & 1.62^{\text{e-05} \\
 \hline
\multirow{2}{3em}{distress} & 0.0007 & 0.004 & 0.0001 & 1.06^{\text{e-04} \\ 
 & -0.002 & -0.002 & -0.07^{\text{e-04} & -6.90^{\text{e-06}} \\
 \hline
\multirow{2}{3em}{grief} & -0.002 & -0.004 & 0.0007* & 0.0007* \\ 
 & -0.005* & -0.006* & 0.00006* & 0.00007* \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{3em}{stress} & 0.002* & -0.001* & 0.0006* & 0.0006* \\ 
 & -0.002* & -0.003* & 0.0002* & 0.0002* \\
\hline
\multirow{2}{3em}{worry} & -0.004 & -0.006* & 0.0005* & 0.0005* \\ 
 & -0.005* & -0.005* & 1.1139 & 0.00001 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
 \label{tab:results}
 \caption{Standardized Regression Coefficients for Year Predicting Severity Index (sev) and Pathologization Index (path) (row 1 = psychology; row 2 = COHCA). + = control analysis. * = \emph{p} < .05.}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

**NOTE**:

HOW IT LOOKS: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CZyq.png)

HOW I WANT IT TO LOOK:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRBZg.png)

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please a) don't post just code fragments we can't compile and b) don't ask multiple questions per post.

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/698741/36296

Answer (score 0):

Regarding issue 2: If you want to separate the row cells for columns 2-5 while keeping the cell in column 1 united, use `\cline{2-5}` like in this example:

```latex
\hline
\multirow{2}{4em}{addiction} & -0.004* & -0.005* & 0.0007* & 0.0008* \\ 
\cline{2-5}
 & -0.008* & -0.008* & 0.00004 & -0.00002 \\
\hline
```

Comment: Amazing! thank you, @Lenka--that is exactly what I needed - and the issue with the figures script was fixed by a colleague who could check the environment until I learn how to ask qs on here.